# Module found in install mode but not in develop mode using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, egg

I'm using `setuptools` for the first time, and trying to package my code so that others can easily develop it. I'm running everything in a virtual environment.

**Short question**: How do I change the directory that the egg-link points to when I run `python setup.py develop`?

**Long question**: The module I'm developing is called `cops_and_robots`. When I run `python setup.py install`, things work fine and I'm able to import my `cops_and_robots` module. However, when I run `python setup.py develop`, running `import cops_and_robots` fails because the `cops_and_robots.egg-link` points to the wrong directory:

```
(cops_and_robots)Antares:cops_and_robots nick$ cat ~/virtual_environments/cops_and_robots/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cops-and-robots.egg-link 
/Users/nick/Downloads/cops_and_robots/
.
```

Here's the directory structure:

```
|____Downloads
| |____cops_and_robots # the whole package directory
| | |____...
| | |____requirements.txt
| | |____setup.py
| | |____src
| | | |____cops_and_robots # the python package directory
| | | |______init.py__
| | |____...
```

And my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import ez_setup
ez_setup.use_setuptools()

setup(
    # Author information and Metadata
    name='cops_and_robots',

    # Package data
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'cops_and_robots':'src/cops_and_robots'},
    include_package_data=True,
    platforms='any',
    requires=['std_msgs','rospy'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    install_requires=[i.strip() for i in open("requirements.txt").readlines()],
)
```

The manual fix is to just append `src/cops_and_robots` to the `cops_and_robots.egg-link` file, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Probably too late for your immediate need, but setuptools `devel` installation has had this problem for a long time. Luckily, there is an easy workaround that might work in your case. Just try changing:

```
# Package data
packages=find_packages('src'),
package_dir={'cops_and_robots':'src/cops_and_robots'},
```

to

```
# Package data
packages=find_packages('src'),
package_dir={'':'src'},
```

in your `setup.py` script.

That case should work well enough with `setuptools` `setup.py devel` and thus with `pip install -e` as well.

For some more background information on this issue, see the following links:

- https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issues/230
- https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issues/177
- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/126