# Module works in install mode but not in develop mode using setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I am facing a similar issue as described in: [Module found in install mode but not in develop mode using setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737431/module-found-in-install-mode-but-not-in-develop-mode-using-setuptools). But the solution is not applicable as I have multiple package_dir instead of one. Similarly, this problem doesn't not occur when using `python3 setup.py install`.

My setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my-project',
      version='0.1',
      description='My project description',
      author='Rishab Manocha',
      package_dir={'': 'module_a/src', 'module_b': 'module_b/src'},
      packages=[
            'module_a1',
            'module_a2',
            'module_b',
            'module_b.module_1b',
            'module_b.module_2b',
      ],
     )
```

When running python3 setup.py develop, the .egg-link only links back to the `module_a/src` and apparently ignores the `module_b/src` completely. This is the output of command `python3 setup.py develop`:

````
running develop
running egg_info
writing module_a/src/my-project.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to module_a/src/my-project.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to module_a/src/my-project.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'module_a/src/my-project.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'module_a/src/my-project.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/orca-airflow.egg-link (link to module_a/src)
Removing orca-airflow 0.1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding orca-airflow 0.1 to easy-install.pth file```
````

Comment: That's a long known issue in `setuptools`, see [#230](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/230)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up refactoring the projects' directory structure to go around this.